# Getting rid of Skype's watermark on video call

Tags: skype

The new Skype shows an annoying "Skype" watermark on video calls in the top-right corner of the screen. Is it possible to get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open Skype
- Click on Tools > Options > Advanced tab
- Un-check the box next to "Show Skype watermark during calls".